# Perform HTTP Get with curl inside a page

Tags: file, http, curl

I have  [this download link](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/3.1.0/php_pthreads-3.1.0-7.0-ts-vc14-x64.zip)

It downloads a zip file when link is clicked oR pasted in browser address bar. If pasted in the browser, the browser performs an http GET and the response forces the browser to download the file.

I want to perform http get from within a php script and force the browser to download the file. How can i achieve this with cURL in php.

I have tried below code but it prints binary response on the browser.

```
$curl = curl_init();
    // Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/3.1.0/php_pthreads-3.1.0-7.0-ts-vc14-x64.zip'
    ));
    // Send the request & save response to $resp
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    // Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

The one thing you can try is simply dump that content instead of capturing it with the right headers. This way your script/server serves as an intermediary instead of a user, as it is right now.

Thus:

```
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/3.1.0/php_pthreads-3.1.0-7.0-ts-vc14-x64.zip'
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="php_pthreads-3.1.0-7.0-ts-vc14-x64.zip"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($resp));
exit($resp);
```